# Pandas: Create a columns based on multiple other columns. Fail to apply()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a dataframe with multiple columns. I want to assign a priority to each row. 
This priority will be given based on the data in the other columns.

I have defined a priority function

```
def priority(Bcat,Brand,IPC,Customer, Type):
    p=1
    if Bcat != "*":
        p+= len(Bcat)/3
    if Brand != "*":
        p+= 2
    if IPC != "*":
        p+= 4
    if Customer != "*" & Customer != "REPLCUST":
        p+= 8
    if Type == "Default":
        p+= -16
    return p
```

And I want now to apply it to my dataframe.

This is what my dataframe looks like (2500 lines):

```
Bcat Brand Customer   IPC   LOC MKT_BUD      Type   STARTEFF    Value
A    B     C          D      E   F            1     2001-01-01    1.0
```

I am trying this but it does not work

```
df["Priority"] = df[["Bcat","Brand","IPC","Customer","Type"]].apply(priority,axis=1,args=("Bcat","Brand","IPC","Customer","Type"))
```

and I get this message

```
TypeError: ('priority() takes 5 positional arguments but 6 were given', 'occurred at index 0')
```

And also tried this

```
df["Priority"] = np.vectorize(priority(df.Bcat,df.Brand,df.IPC,df.Customer,df.Type))
```

and got this message

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use an apply on your dataframe you might need a lambda function:

```
def priority(Bcat,Brand,IPC,Customer, Type):
    p=1
    if Bcat != "*":
        p+= len(Bcat)/3
    if Brand != "*":
        p+= 2
    if IPC != "*":
        p+= 4
    if (Customer != "*") & (Customer != "REPLCUST"): # Here you need brackets
        p+= 8
    if Type == "Default":
        p+= -16
    return p

df= pd.DataFrame([['A','B','C','D','E','F','1','2001-01-01','1.0']],\
     columns = ['Bcat','Brand','Customer','IPC','LOC','MKT_BUD','Type','STARTEFF','Value'])

df.apply(lambda x: priority(x.Bcat,x.Brand,x.IPC,x.Customer,x.Type),axis = 1)

0    15.333333
dtype: float64
```

This will work on a dataframe thus it is possibly not optimal as it loops over the rows to get access to the length of the string in `df.BCat`. I will look for something more efficient.

**EDIT:**

Otherwise you can use `str.len` to perform the column wise operation:

```
df['priority'] = 1
mask = df.Bcat != "*"
df.loc[mask,'priority'] += df.loc[mask,'Bcat'].str.len()/3
df.loc[df.Brand != "*",'priority'] += 2
df.loc[df.IPC != "*",'priority'] += 4
df.loc[~df.Customer.isin(['*','REPLCUST']),'priority'] += 8
df.loc[df.Type == "Default",'priority'] -= 16

    Bcat    Brand   Customer    IPC LOC MKT_BUD Type  STARTEFF    Value priority
0   A       B       C           D   E   F       1     2001-01-01  1.0   15.333333
```

This will be way faster as you work on Series instead of looping over the rows.

Comment: I went through all the solutions and I think your implementation will be the fastest. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is a vectorized solution applied across all the rows simultaneously.  It should run much faster than applying the function to each row on its own.

```
def priority(df):
    df = df.assign(priority=1)
    df['Type'] = df['Type'].astype(str)
    mask = df['Bcat'] != '*'
    df.loc[mask, 'priority'] += df.loc[mask, 'Bcat'].apply(len) / 3.
    df.loc[df['Brand'] != '*', 'priority'] += 2
    df.loc[df['IPC'] != '*', 'priority'] += 4
    df.loc[~df['Customer'].isin(['*', 'REPLCUST']), 'priority'] += 8
    df.loc[df['Type'] == 'Default', 'priority'] -= 16
    return df

>>> priority(df)
  Bcat Brand Customer IPC LOC MKT_BUD Type    STARTEFF  Value   priority
0    A     B        C   D   E       F    1  2001-01-01      1  15.333333
```

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, apply can do the trick here.

I create this test:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3], [6,7,8]], columns=[1,2,3])
def func(a, b, c):
    return a + b + c
df['total'] = df.apply(lambda row: func(row[1], row[2], row[3]), axis='columns')
```

output:

```
    1   2   3   total
0   1   2   3   6
1   6   7   8   21
```

my fix to your apply code would be:

```
df= pd.DataFrame([['A','B','C','D','E','F','1','2001-01-01','1.0']],\
     columns = ['Bcat','Brand','Customer','IPC','LOC','MKT_BUD','Type','STARTEFF','Value'])


df['Priority'] = df.apply(lambda row: priority(row['Bcat'], 
                                               row['Brand'], 
                                               row['IPC'], 
                                               row['Customer'], 
                                               row['Type']), 
                          axis='columns')
```

Output:

```
    Bcat   Brand    Customer    IPC LOC MKT_BUD Type  STARTEFF     Value    Priority
0   A      B        C           D   E   F        1    2001-01-01    1.0     15.333333
```

Comment: @ysearka I just tested using the dataframe you defined in your solution. I did not get any errors. in my case len(Bcat) = 1

Comment: And this seems to work on a dataframe containing several lines, so it is indeed the length of the string in the cell. Nice solution!